# Difference between jsforce bulk api options

Tags: javascript, salesforce, bulk, jsforce

I'm using [jsforce](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce) to access salesforce using the bulk api. It has two ways of updating and deleting records. One is using the normal bulk api which means creating a job and batches:

```
var job = conn.bulk.createJob("Account", "delete");
var batch = job.createBatch();
var accounts = getAccountsByDate(jsforce.Date.TODAY);
batch.execute(accounts);

batch.on('response', function(rets) {
    // do things
});
```

The other way is to the "query" interface like this:

```
conn.sobject('Account')
    .find({ CreatedDate: jsforce.Date.TODAY })
    .destroy(function(err, rets) {
        // do things
    });
```

The second way certainly seems easier but I can't get it to update or delete more than 10,000 records at a time, which appears to be a salesforce api [limit on batch size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm). Note that using `maxFetch` property from `jsforce` appears to have no effect in this case.

So is it safe to assume that the query style interface only creates a single batch? The [jsforce documentation](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#update-delete-queried-records) is not clear on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the bulk.load() method in JSforce bulk api generates a job with one batch, so the limit of 10,000 per batch will be applied. It is also true when using find-and-destroy interface, which uses bulk.load() internally.
To avoid this limit you can create a job by bulk.createJob() and create several batches by job.createBatch(), then dispatch the records to delete into these batches so that each records will not exceed the limit.